# Filter null case when reading in keys from YAML with yq

Tags: bash, yaml, yq

Say I have a yaml file, `example.yaml`:

```
test:
services:
  registry:
    image: registry:2
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "337:337"
  pinger:
    build:
```

I can read in the services to a bash array like so:

```
readarray -t services  <<< $(yq e '.services | keys | .[]' example.yaml)
```

But when I try the case where the key has no sub-keys, I get an error:

```
yq e '.test | keys | .[]' example.yaml
Error: Cannot get keys of !!null, keys only works for maps and arrays
```

What is a good way of replacing the null case with a falsey value? Ultimately I'd like `test` to be stored as a bash variable ( `== false`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the select() function in combination with the not operator to filter out the null values before applying the keys function like this;

```
yq e '.test | select(.) | keys | .[]' example.yaml
```

The select(.) expression will return all non-null values in the test key. You can use the same approach for those keys as well:

```
yq e '.test | select(.) | keys | .[]' example.yaml
yq e '.services | select(.) | keys | .[]' example.yaml
```

Comment: For "replacing the null case with a falsey value", you can use the alternative operator `//` as in `yq e '(.test, .services) | (select(.) | keys | .[]) // false'`

Comment: @pmf neat. I was thinking to do `if [ -z "$test"]; then echo 'test is false'; fi` type of thing in bash, but this is better. Could warrant a separate answer?

Comment: Where is the "not operator" in any of the snippets in this answer, if I may ask?